# sas coding issue with if statement

Tags: sas

I use if statement to create a new variable, but is not working. I checked around and cannot find where is the problem.

```
data sockeye;
 infile 'c:/sockeye.csv';
 length data $8.;  
 input data $ sockeye;
 if data='29-Jul' then sampweight =250/15;
 if data='30-Jul' then sampweight =250/15;
run;

data n_boats;
 length data$8.;
 data = '29-Jul';_total_=250;output;
 data = '30-Jul';_total_=250;output;
run;

proc surveymeans data=sockeye N=n_boats mean sum;
 strata data / list;
 var sockeye;
 weight sampweight;
run;
```

Comment: what do sockeye and n_boats look like? after the data steps

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected? Be more specific about the problem.

Comment: You should change the second "if" to "else if" and then add another line under it like this `else put _all_;` to see if it is comparing what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, you are trying to read a .csv file. This is better done with the import wizard, in my experience.  This is esp. true for dates, which are difficult to deal with in SAS (and many other programs).

For the second part variables with _ prefix and suffix are created by SAS. I am not positive, but I don't think you can alter them; I would recommend against trying.

In general, I'd avoid having variables named things like 'data' which is a keyword in SAS. Also, that variable name is uninformative. Clearly, these are dates. So, the variable name should be something like dateXXX where the XXX indicates what the date is.

Comment: While SAS does often use names like `_<var>_`, there is no restriction on using this convention to users.  The only ones I'm aware of SAS using in the data step (and thus to be avoided) are `_ERROR_` and `_N_`, along with the automatic variable lists `_ALL_` `_CHARACTER_` and `_NUMERIC_`.